# Call parent Javascript function from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent

I have a iframe (in my domain), that iframe has a file `iframe.js`.

My parent document has a file `parent.js`.

I need to call a function that is in `parent.js`, from a function that is in `iframe.js`.

I tried doing `window.parent.myfunction()` this function is in the `parent.js` file.

But, it  didn't work. Only when I put the function on the parent page (I mean in the HTML), then it worked.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: please provide some snippets. How the methods are declared and the iframe constelation.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try just `parent.myfunction()`. Also be 100% sure that the parent.js is included in your parent document.

Comment: does this work in all browsers and is part of the javascript standard?

Comment: It's tested in IE, Chrome and FF. Not sure if it's written into the standards or not.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - NP, it's what this community is about. Proud to be a part of it.

Comment: Using parent.function(), does not work for me in IE. I solved this by using window.top in front. "window.top.function();"

Answer (score 35):

I know this is an old question, but in case the accepted answer doesn't work (it didn't work for me) you could do this inside parent.js

```
window.myfunction = function () {
   alert("I was called from a child iframe");
}
```

Now from the iframe you can call *myfunction()* like you initially wanted

```
window.parent.myfunction();
```

Comment: Nice trick!  This actually works.  I am not sure what is the difference between "window.myfunction = function()" and "function myfunction()".  Any idea?

Answer (score 17):

**`Window.postMessage()`** method safely enables `cross-origin` communication.

If you have access to parent page then any data can be passed as well as any parent method can be called directly from `Iframe`.

**Parent page:**

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);        
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", onMessage, false);
}

function onMessage(event) {
    // Check sender origin to be trusted
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.com") return;

    var data = event.data;      
    if (typeof(window[data.func]) == "function") {
        window[data.func].call(null, data.message);
    }
}

// Function to be called from iframe
function parentFuncName(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

**Iframe code:**

```
window.parent.postMessage({
    'func': 'parentFuncName',
    'message': 'Message text from iframe.'
}, "*");
```

**References:**

- Cross-document messaging (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging)
- Window.postMessage method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- Can I Use (http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage)

Comment: 1up for mentioning cross origin and a well accepted solution

Comment: This is one of the greatest coding methods

Comment: It's great for communicate between iframes you open for pages on other domains, cross-origin communication as it is